# character fading effect in QT application

Tags: qt, character, displaytag, fading

I am having an issue with character displaying with QT (running on dm365), that some times random pixels are missed from character. Images attached for reference. Please guide me to move ahead.

[image: Picture with several buttons where pixels are missing]

Comment: What Qt version? What is the exact platform?

Comment: QT everywhere commercial 4.6.3 version, and platform is dm365 working with kernel 2.6.18_pro500-davinci_evm-arm_v5t_le. montavista linux

Comment: Ok, what's the code used to paint the buttons? It'd be good for you to add a minimal, one-file testcase to the question - just enough to compile, run and show the buttons, while still demonstrating the issue for you.

Comment: just add button in .ui file with stylesheet "font: 16pt "Sans Serif";\ncolor: rgb(0, 0, 0);" and ya i use only one file to minimize efforts and still getting issue. One thing i want to add that i get screenshot by coping of frame buffer, and there is no fadding effect seen on screenshot.

Comment: You have faulty hardware, then.